# Prevent Screen tearing Kubuntu 18.10?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors

After (and before) installing NVidia drivers, I am experiencing a lot of screen tearing in both Chrome and Graveyard Keeper (an apparently native to linux steam game)

I have 2 monitors, one plugged in by HDMI, and a GSYNC compatible monitor plugged in via Display Port.

However they only show up as one screen in NVIDIA X Server Settings?

I have Sync to VBlank, Allow G-Sync, and Enable G-Sync indicator all enabled, but I do not see the GSync indicator appear.

I've tried disabling Sync to VBlank to no success, I figured if GSYNC was off, I could at least get a stable FPS in this (low gfx req) game or chrome, but to no avail.

Monitor A: is an old 1920x1200 monitor plugged in HDMI, keeps stealing the default monitor status in bios, and linux has been tending to forget my preferences for the other monitor to be primary.

Monitor B: I wish this would stick to being my primary monitor, plugged in via Display Port, capable of GSYNC, and 2560x1440 (with display scaling enabled)

[image: Monitor Setup]

This monitor IS cabable of 144hz (I've seen it under windows) and I've had GSYNC working in the past.

I installed Kubuntu after getting frustrated at the recent windows update that killed my windows install, and seeing several people saying that 'gaming on linux is so much better then it was' but if it can't even get something as simple as V-Sync right, I'm not sure that's true.

[image: Nvidia X server settings]

Comment: Try updating to Nvidia driver 410. I think that has some issues solved with 4k monitors. ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu has the latest drivers.